# JS Find closest on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the closest `.cat-dropdown-menu` to the clicked `.title` so that only one dropdown fires at once. I think I need to reconfigure this part of the code to find the closest `.cat-dropdown-menu` on click but I'm not sure.

```
$(".cat-dropdown .title").click(function() {
  if ($container.height() > 0) {
    closeMenu(this);
  } else {
    openMenu(this);
  }
});
```

```js
var $container = $('.cat-dropdown-menu'),
  $list = $('.cat-dropdown-menu .cat-list'),
  listItem = $list.find('.cat-item');

$(".cat-dropdown .title").click(function() {
  if ($container.height() > 0) {
    closeMenu(this);
  } else {
    openMenu(this);
  }
});

$(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item").click(function() {
  closeMenu(this);
});

function closeMenu(el) {
  $(el)
    .closest(".cat-dropdown")
    .toggleClass("closed")
    .find(".title")
    .text($(el).text())
    .css('color', el.style.color);
  $container.css("height", 0);
  $list.css("top", 0);
}


function openMenu(el) {
  $(el).parent().toggleClass("closed");

  $container.css({
      height: 200
    })
    .mousemove(function(e) {
      var heightDiff = $list.height() / $container.height(),
        offset = $container.offset(),
        relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top),
        top = relativeY * heightDiff > $list.height() - $container.height() ?
        $list.height() - $container.height() : relativeY * heightDiff;

      $list.css("top", -top);
    });
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat-dropdown {
  text-align: left;
  color: #343c3f;
  border: 1px solid #a2acb0;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item {
  height: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title:after {
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .title {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
}

.cat-dropdown .title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "▾";
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: "border-box";
  -moz-box-sizing: "border-box";
  box-sizing: "border-box";
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
  padding: 0 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item:hover {
  background-color: #d9e1e4;
  color: #343c3f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="title">
    <label>Pick 2</label></div>
  <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="cat-list">
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#3772b1">Henry Christensen</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#4eaddc">Lamar Flynn</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#ff9148">Jameson Davidson</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="title">
    <label>Pick 2</label></div>
  <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="cat-list">
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#3772b1">Henry Christensen</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#4eaddc">Lamar Flynn</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#ff9148">Jameson Davidson</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `var $container = $('.cat-dropdown-menu')` or `$list = $('.cat-dropdown-menu .cat-list')` you're getting all menus on the page. You should instead get only the ones related to the title clicked. Moving these variables into the scope of the click event and limiting them to the clicked item should fix the problem.

e.g.

```js
$(".cat-dropdown .title").click(function() {
var $menu = $(this).siblings('.cat-dropdown-menu')
  if ($menu.height() > 0) {
    closeMenu($menu);
  } else {
    openMenu($menu);
  }
});

$(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item").click(function() {
  var $menu = $(this).parents('.cat-dropdown-menu')
  closeMenu($menu);
  $menu
    .closest(".cat-dropdown")
    .find(".title")
    .text($(this).text())
    .css('color', this.style.color);
});

function closeMenu($menu) {
  $list = $menu.children('.cat-list');
  
  $menu
    .closest(".cat-dropdown")
    .toggleClass("closed");
  $menu.css("height", 0);
  $list.css("top", 0);
}


function openMenu($menu) {
  $list = $menu.children('.cat-list');
  
  $menu.parent().toggleClass("closed");

  $menu.css({
      height: 200
    })
    .mousemove(function(e) {
      var heightDiff = $list.height() / $menu.height(),
        offset = $menu.offset(),
        relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top),
        top = relativeY * heightDiff > $list.height() - $menu.height() ?
        $list.height() - $menu.height() : relativeY * heightDiff;

      $list.css("top", -top);
    });
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat-dropdown {
  text-align: left;
  color: #343c3f;
  border: 1px solid #a2acb0;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item {
  height: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title:after {
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .title {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
}

.cat-dropdown .title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "▾";
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: "border-box";
  -moz-box-sizing: "border-box";
  box-sizing: "border-box";
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
  padding: 0 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item:hover {
  background-color: #d9e1e4;
  color: #343c3f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="title">
    <label>Pick 2</label></div>
  <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="cat-list">
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#3772b1">Henry Christensen</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#4eaddc">Lamar Flynn</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#ff9148">Jameson Davidson</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="title">
    <label>Pick 2</label></div>
  <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="cat-list">
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#3772b1">Henry Christensen</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#4eaddc">Lamar Flynn</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#ff9148">Jameson Davidson</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good approach, thanks. However right now the menu doesn't close when an item is selected.